# How to make a regex for a textarea?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have this regex

```
var message_regex   = /^[a-z]{10,500}$/;
```

It checks, if the user has entered a minimum of 10 characters. It works good but if I include a blank space in it, it doesn't count it as a character?

Example:

```
asdfasdfas
```

The above counts as 10 characters

```
asdas asda s
```

The above doesn't count as 10 characters.

How do I add blank spaces and special characters to this regex?

Comment: so numbers can't be entered?

Comment: Why not `str.length > 9 && str.length < 501`, depending on the rest of the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why just not use the `.` to match every character?

```
var message_regex = /^.{10,500}$/;
```

This makes sure the textarea has between 10 to 500 characters.

Comment: Thank you so much that works good and is shorter to the one I just tried `[A-Za-z\W\s]`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var message_regex   = /^[a-z ]{10,500}$/;
```

Note the space at the end of a-z